# jdbc batch performance

Tags: performance, postgresql, jdbc, batch-file

i'm batching updates with jdbc

```
ps = con.prepareStatement("");
ps.addBatch();
ps.executeBatch();
```

but in the background it seems, that the prostgres driver sends the query bit by bit to the database.

org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl:398

```
 for (int i = 0; i < queries.length; ++i)
            {
                V3Query query = (V3Query)queries[i];
                V3ParameterList parameters = (V3ParameterList)parameterLists[i];
                if (parameters == null)
                    parameters = SimpleQuery.NO_PARAMETERS;

                sendQuery(query, parameters, maxRows, fetchSize, flags, trackingHandler);

                if (trackingHandler.hasErrors())
                    break;
            }
```

is there a possibility to let him send 1000 a time to speed it up?

Comment: PostgreSQL version? JDBC driver version? What are the queries you're batching? As for the code, it looks like you're talking about `execute(Query[] queries, ParameterList[] parameterLists, ...)`

Comment: i'm batching updates, driver is "9.1-901-1.jdbc4". I found the copy api. But i couldn't find any docs abount the format it's reading. Just "from - a CSV file or such" http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html#copyIn%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream%29

Comment: The copy command should be a wrapper around COPY used by Postgres in general. More information here on the format and command: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: Filed: https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/15

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<del>AFAIK is no server-side batching in the [fe/be protocol](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol-overview.html), so PgJDBC can't use it.</del>. *Update*: Well, I was wrong. PgJDBC (accurate as of 9.3) *does* send batches of queries to the server *if it doesn't need to fetch generated keys*. It just queues a bunch of queries up in the send buffer without syncing up with the server after each individual query.

See:

- [Issue #15: Enable batching when returning generated keys](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/15)
- [Issue #195:  PgJDBC does not pipeline batches that return generated keys](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/195)

Even when generated keys are requested the [extended query protocol](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol-overview.html#PROTOCOL-QUERY-CONCEPTS) is used to ensure that the query text doesn't need to be sent every time, just the parameters.

Frankly, JDBC batching isn't a great solution in any case. It's easy to use for the app developer, but pretty sub-optimal for performance as the server still has to execute every statement individually - though not *parse* and *plan* them individually so long as you use prepared statements.

If autocommit is on, performance will be absolutely pathetic because each statement triggers a commit. Even with autocommit off running lots of little statements won't be particularly fast even if you could eliminate the round-trip delays.

A better solution for lots of simple `UPDATE`s can be to:

- `COPY` new data into a `TEMPORARY` or `UNLOGGED` table; and
- Use `UPDATE ... FROM` to `UPDATE` with a `JOIN` against the copied table

For COPY, see [the PgJDBC docs](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html#copyIn%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream%29) and [the `COPY` documentation in the server docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html).

You'll often find it's possible to tweak things so your app doesn't have to send all those individual `UPDATE`s at all.