# What is the max JDBC batch size?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jdbc, batch-processing

I have a list and that list increasing continuously. I am doing add batch depend on the list size. I forgot to put limit for do executeBatch in specified size.

Program is working for hours. I dont want to stop, fix and start again for now.

My questions, what decides size of the adding batch? What is the max capacity of the batch to do `executeBatch()` in a one time? How many time I can use `addBatch` without do `executeBatch()`?

Comment: IMO there is no actual limit other than memory size. You might want to check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639118/jdbc-batch-performance .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PgJDBC has some limitations regarding batches:

- All request values, and all results, must be accumulated in memory. This includes large blob/clob results. So free memory is the main limiting factor for batch size.
- [Until PgJDBC 9.4 (not yet released)](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/pull/204), [batches that return generated keys always do a round trip for every entry](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/195), so they're no better than individual statement executions.
- Even in 9.4, batches that return generated keys only offer a benefit if the generated values are size limited. [A single `text`, `bytea` or unconstrained `varchar` field  in the requested result will force the driver to do a round trip for every execution](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pgjdbc/commit/1471bd93fce5401c8bc80f686f8beace9572ec79).

The benefit of batching is a reduction in network round trips. So there's much less point if your DB is local to your app server. There's a diminishing return with increasing batch size, because the total time taken in network waits falls off quickly, so it's often not work stressing about trying to make batches as big as possible.

If you're bulk-loading data, seriously consider using the `COPY` API instead, via PgJDBC's `CopyManager`, obtained via the `PgConnection` interface. It lets you stream CSV-like data to the server for rapid bulk-loading with very few client/server round trips. Unfortunately, it's remarkably under-documented - it doesn't appear in the main PgJDBC docs at all, [only in the API docs](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html).

Comment: Did you mean to write "there's actually very *little* benefit to doing batches"? Also, does the client/server round trip issue you mentioned still hold true with the v3 protocol and the latest PgJDBC driver? To my eye, `org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl#execute` looks like it might not be waiting for a round trip.

Comment: @ScottDudley I've amended the question based on later work I did. In short, it waits between executions only if generated keys have been requested, otherwise it'll send the batch in large chunks. It guestimates the number of entries per batch by trying to guess the server's send buffer size and the response size. [It's all a bit crude and backwards, but it works](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/194)

Comment: Does OP understand that this answer is driver specific (PostgreSQL)? Consider clarifying the answer as a driver specific explanation of limitations through the JDBC interface.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no limit beside the memory issue. 
regarding your question: the statement is sent to the DB only on execute batch so until you'll execute the batch the memory will continue to grow until you will get JavaHeapSpace or the batch will be sent to the DB.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a maximum number of parameter markers depending on the JDBC implementation.

For instance the PostgreSQL driver represents the number of parameters [as a 2-byte integer](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/16832734.post@talk.nabble.com), which in Java is at most 32768.