# sqlserver jdbc batchsize limit

Tags: java, jdbc, sql-server-2012

Is there any limit on number of records in a JDBC batch?

I am using sqljdbc4-4.0 to connect with SQL Server 2012 DB.

Please point me to reference documentation for this, if available.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883964/what-is-the-max-jdbc-batch-size) 
As per JDBC it seems there is no such limit on the records in a batch insert, Its all governed  by the memory available.