# Is it possible to merge multiple insert statements to 1 insert statement in hibernate with postgres db?

Tags: java, hibernate

For the purpose of optimizing big insert processes in our system, we intend to batch in our insert sql statements. But no matter what I configure, so far, I'm not able to accomplish that.

Based on the answer on this SO question:
[Hibernate batch size confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687422/hibernate-batch-size-confusion)

It should be possible.

I already configured the hibernate.jdbc.batch_size property but still was not able to batch the insert statements? I can confirm this by enabling sql logs on both hibernate side and the postgres server side.

Is it possible to merge multiple insert statements to 1 insert statement in hibernate with postgres db?

Sample entity I used below:

```
class GenericMessage {
    String name
    //other fields
}
```

I'm using GORM, so it's on groovy (These are done in a transaction):

```
GenericMessage message1 = new GenericMessage(name: 'name1').save()
GenericMessage message2 = new GenericMessage(name: 'name2').save()
session.flush()
session.clear()
```

Comment: [Duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121711/hibernate-multi-row-insert-postgresql) Not sure. Short answer seems to be that `rewriteBatchedStatements` is a MySQL specific JDBC driver parameter and that this is not relevant to Postgres - see [this message thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/828427796@web.de) where the team argue that such a rewrite would be both complex and pointless.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I'm under the impression that the Postgres team likes to argue about any proposed features ;)

Comment: @Kayaman no idea - don't use Postgres; but if they're anything like the Java team... I suppose either way, though, there's no way to do what the OP wants. Not sure if it's a duplicate - obviously feel free to dup-hammer it if you think it is.

Comment: Can you post your code... I mean the entity that you're trying to insert and the code where your persist your entity, please?

Comment: @CarlitosWay Updated the question. Simplified it a bit. Hopefully that's ok.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `GORM`, but why `GenericMessage` does not have JPA Annotations, like `@Entity` for example??

Comment: @CarlitosWay Please assume that they are annotated with Entity. GORM just omits those in favor of convention over configuration.

Comment: Ok... I'm just asking because if you read links as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639118/jdbc-batch-performance/12648498#12648498) one... It will tell you that your batch insert will be affected by your Entity ID generation strategy...

Comment: @CarlitosWay the post also says that regardless of whether queries are batched performance won't be improved, which agrees with the data [in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41744475/is-it-possible-to-merge-multiple-insert-statements-to-1-insert-statement-in-hibe#comment70681699_41744475). So I would suggest to the OP that this is a dead end.